# How to apply a difference equation to a numpy array inside for loop

Tags: python, numpy, filter, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to apply a simple difference equation to a numpy array as part of a filtering algorithm. The problem is that python reassigns the numpy variables inside the for loop and thus returns a list of zeros. How to I restructure this code to pass the numpy arrays by reference to the for loop?

```
def resonant_ladder_filter(vector_in, fc, res):

    fs = 44100 
    fs2 = 2*fs 



    in2 = signal.decimate(vector_in, 2)

    h = signal.firwin(10, 0.5)

    in2 = signal.lfilter(h,1,in2)

    g = 2*np.pi*fc/fs2 

    Gres = res; 

    h0 = g/1.3; h1 = g*0.3/1.3; 

    w = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

    wold = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

    Gcomp = 0.5; 

    out = np.zeros(len(vector_in))

    out2 = np.zeros(len(in2))

    for n in range(0,len(in2)):
        u = in2[n] - 4*Gres*(wold[4] - Gcomp*in2[n])

        w[0] = np.tanh(u) 


        w[1] = h0*w[0] + h1*wold[0] + (1-g)*wold[1]
        w[2] = h0*w[1] + h1*wold[1] + (1-g)*wold[2]
        w[3] = h0*w[2] + h1*wold[2] + (1-g)*wold[3]
        w[4] = h0*w[3] + h1*wold[3] + (1-g)*wold[4]

        out2[n] = w[4]

        wold = w

    out2 = signal.lfilter(h,1,out2)

    out = signal.decimate(out2, 2)

    return out
```

This code is essentially written in a matlab style, and doesn't plug and play nicely with python as is. There must be a better, pythonic way to write this, I just can't work that out.

Comment: Hi K.Numm, I think there may be a very easy answer that skips the whole for-loop, with numpy vectorized diff operator.  If you provide a "before" matrix and "after" matrix with the "mask" matrix or filter, I can show you how to do it with numpy without for-loop.  It's kind of difficult now for me to figure out your sample. :-)

Comment: `in2 = np.zeros(2*len(vector_in))` looks unnecessary because you immediately have `in2 = signal.decimate(vector_in, 2)`

Comment: @gboffi This is correct,  thank you, but it does not affect the problem at hand.

Comment: @JenniferE.Yoon I think you are right, I had a look at numpy vectorize before posting this but could not work out how to apply it in this instance

Answer (score 1):

--
Hi k.munn,

I believe your issue has to do with variable assignment vs. copying.

This line is your problem:

```
wold = w
```

Change it to:

```
wold = w.copy()
```

It will create a copy of your numpy.array which should resolve your issue.

See the general documentation here: [Python docs - copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html), or here [Numpy docs - copy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html)

Hope this helps!

---

EDIT:

Running the code surfaced an element assignment issue within the numpy arrays as they are initialised as integer zeros:

```
w = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])
```

Changing this to (for wold respectively):

```
w = np.zeros(5, dtype=np.float64)
```

Should allow

```
w[0] = np.tanh(u)
```

to insert the values correctly.

Comment: Thanks Joe Ernst, 

The problem initially occurs before this point. As far as I understand, when


w[0] = np.tanh(u)


is applied, a new list is created. Not modifying the numpy array as I intend

Comment: Hey k.munn alright, so after running your code, I realised there might be a different problem with it. 

You initialise your w and wold arrays as integer zeros. Then you try to assign it np.float64 scalars which are the output of the np.tanh(u) call.

Change your initialisation to:

w = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.float64)
wold = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.float64)

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

I will update my answer above to include this.

Comment: Miscounted... should be np.zeros(5, dtype=np.float64). Changed the answer accordingly.